# Get first line from raw text using python

Tags: python, regex

I want get the name (first line only) from the below raw content. Can you please help me? I want to get just `RAM KUMAR` only from the raw text using python.

Raw Content:

```
"RAM KUMAR\n\nMarketing and Sales Professional\n\n+91.0000000000\n\nshri.babuji@shriresume.com, shri1.babuji@shriresume.com\n\nLinkedin.com/in/ramkumar              \t\t\t\t                           \n\n\t\t\t\n\n      \t                                                                                   \n\nSUMMARY\n\n\n\nHighly motivated, creative and versatile IT professional with 9.2 years of experience in Java, J2SE & J2EE and related technologies as Developer, Onsite/Offshore Coordinator and Project Lead.\n\nProficiency in Java, Servlets, Struts and the latest frameworks like JSF, EJB 3.0.\n\nKnowledge of Java, JSP, Servlet, EJB, JMS, Struts and spring, Hibernate, XML, Web Services.\n\nExperience in using MVC design pattern, Java, Servlets, JSP, JavaScript, Hibernate 3.0, Web Services (SOAP and Restful), HTML, JQuery, XML, Web Logic, JBOSS 4.2.3, SQL, PL/SQL, JUnit, and Apache-Tomcat, Linux.\n\nExtensive experience in developing various web based applications using Struts framework.\n\nExpertise in relational databases like Oracle, My SQL and SQL Server.\n\nExperienced in developing Web Based applications using Web Sphere 6.0 and Oracle 9i as a back end."
```

Comment: split by `'\n'` or match by regexp

Comment: Is that raw content kept in a file? Also, probably you'll get downvotes because you have show no trace of struggling to solve the issue..

Comment: @ vahdet. That raw text not a just variable value or now saved file, that data convert from doc to raw txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use regex, just simply do:

```
print(yourstring.split('\n')[0])
```

Output:

```
RAM KUMAR
```

**Edit:**

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    print(f.read().split('\n')[0])
```

Comment: That raw text not a just variable value or now saved file, that data convert from doc to raw txt

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  i have fixed using txt_content = txt_content.decode('string-escape')
  print(txt_content.split('\n')[0])

Comment: @RaguNatarajan Happy to help, :-), Please accept if it works, and up-vote :D

Answer (score 3):

Use [`split`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/) to do something like this perhaps:

```
txt_content = "RAM KUMAR\n\nMarketing and Sales Professional\n\n+91.0000000000\n\nshri.babuji@shriresume.com, shri1.babuji@shriresume.com\n\nLinkedin.com/in/ramkumar              \t\t\t\t                           \n\n\t\t\t\n\n      \t                                                                                   \n\nSUMMARY\n\n\n\nHighly motivated, creative and versatile IT professional with 9.2 years of experience in Java, J2SE & J2EE and related technologies as Developer, Onsite/Offshore Coordinator and Project Lead.\n\nProficiency in Java, Servlets, Struts and the latest frameworks like JSF, EJB 3.0.\n\nKnowledge of Java, JSP, Servlet, EJB, JMS, Struts and spring, Hibernate, XML, Web Services.\n\nExperience in using MVC design pattern, Java, Servlets, JSP, JavaScript, Hibernate 3.0, Web Services (SOAP and Restful), HTML, JQuery, XML, Web Logic, JBOSS 4.2.3, SQL, PL/SQL, JUnit, and Apache-Tomcat, Linux.\n\nExtensive experience in developing various web based applications using Struts framework.\n\nExpertise in relational databases like Oracle, My SQL and SQL Server.\n\nExperienced in developing Web Based applications using Web Sphere 6.0 and Oracle 9i as a back end."
print(txt_content.split('\n')[0])    # 'RAM KUMAR'
```

Comment: Well, isn't that a replica of mine? not asking you to delete this.

Comment: @U9-Forward They say that imitation is a sign of flattery :P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, Lol :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually i have fixed using txt_content.decode('string-escape')

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), I am offering a regex-based solution for the same.

Use the following expression:

`^[^\n]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h40abu/1)

All I am doing is matching everything except the `'\n'` charatcer from the beginning of the line.

The first match will then be the result you are interested in.